# Swift - 8tracks.com API POST json data fails (422) everytime

Tags: objective-c, json, api, swift, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to talk with 8tracks open API in Swift iOS app. I need to make POST authorization request to `http://8tracks.com/sessions.json`with AFNetworking but everytime I get `422 Unprocessable Entity` error..

I tried this endpoint on the web and it works fine. Here is code that I'm using (subclassing `AFHTTPSessionManager`):

```
init() {
    super.init()

    self.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
    self.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()

    self.requestSerializer.setValue(API_KEY, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Api-Key")
    self.requestSerializer.setValue("3", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Api-Version")
}

func login(username: String, password: String, success: (NSURLSessionDataTask!, AnyObject!) -> Void, failure: ((NSURLSessionDataTask!, NSError!) -> Void)?) {
    let credentials = ["username": username, "password": password] as Dictionary

    self.POST(
        API_URL.stringByAppendingString("/sessions.json"),
        parameters: credentials,
        success: success,
        failure: failure
    )
}
```

Error looks as follows:

```
{ URL: http://8tracks.com/sessions.json } { status code: 422, headers {
"Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
Age = 0;
"Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 125;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Wed, 25 Jun 2014 19:29:12 GMT";
Server = "nginx/1.4.3";
Status = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
Via = "1.1 varnish";
"X-Action" = "sessions/create";
"X-Backend" = rails;
"X-Cache" = MISS;
"X-Data-Request" = 1;
"X-Request-Id" = 3040c8bf79936b27075731f634bfd534;
"X-Requests-Left" = 99;
"X-Runtime" = "0.257240";
"X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: client error (422), 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://8tracks.com/sessions.json}
```

Comment: You mentioned "I tried this endpoint on the web and it works fine". You were able to POST or GET?

Comment: @YarGnawh I made POST requests with json data with Javascript to auth and it worked well

Comment: why minus the question??

Comment: hmmm. based on your console log, it doesn't seem like your headers are being assigned. I don't see "X-Api-Key" or "X-Api-Version". log `self.requestSerializer.HTTPRequestHeaders` before you make the post and see if the headers are set.

Comment: @YarGnawh everything's fine here too.. ``{
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1";
    "User-Agent" = "MY_APP/1 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 8.0; Scale/2.00)";
    "X-Api-Key" = MY_KEY;
    "X-Api-Version" = 3;
}``

Comment: @YarGnawh I will try to make plain request now with ``NSMutableURLRequest`` and if it will fail then it seems that 8tracks have some restrictions.. based on user-agent maybe..

Comment: yeah, plain ``NSMutbaleURLRequest`` failed as well.. and change of user-agent didn't help unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have something to do with subclass AFHTTPSessionManager without a baseURL. I've tested the following code and it works.

```
let path = "/sessions.json"
let params = ["login": login, "password": password, "api_version": "3"]

let success = {(task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, response: AnyObject!) -> Void in
    println(response)
}

let failure = {(task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    println(error)
}

var client = AFHTTPSessionManager(baseURL:  NSURL(string: "https://8tracks.com"))
client.POST(path, parameters: params, success: success, failure: failure)
```

Comment: the problem was very very stupid.. I've mixed up ``login`` and ``username`` :)